# table view date selected only the long press

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I'm using the `tableViewCell` in `Xib`.

In table view, `didSelectRowAt` function is only called when I long press the `tableViewCell`

My Code is below

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        categorytabelview.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        self.categorylabel.text = totalArrayofCars.object(at: indexPath.row) as? String
        categorytabelview.isHidden = true
    }
```

I want to select the `tabelViewCell` data in single select not in long press.

[image: My tabel view is displaye above the select carcategory button]

Comment: Did you added any gesture recognizer above it?

Comment: no, i did not add any gesture recongnizer

Comment: Why are you deselecting the row once you selects the cell?

Comment: yes I commented this line  categorytabelview.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true) and I run my code, i got the same error

Comment: Are you using any third party library?

Comment: No i did'nt  use any third party library for table view

Comment: Yes i'm using tap gesture  for hiding the key board

Comment: @kumaresh saran can you please show your view hierarchy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using gesture, right before adding the gesture to view, add the following line

```
tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false // assuming tap is your gesture recogniser variable
```

Comment: thank you guys I got a solution. tap.canceltouchInView = false is working for my below my code is . '  let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ADEditProfileVC.hidekeyboard))
        
        tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
       
        tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)'